# Symfony2 Form Button Configuration

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

Reading through the Form Button Configuration of [Symfony 2.7 best practices](http://symfony.com/pdf/Symfony_best_practices_2.7.pdf) (page 27) it says:

> Form classes should try to be agnostic to where they will be used. This makes them easier to re-use later.
>   Add buttons in the templates, not in the form classes or the controllers.

I can see the benefit of not having the buttons in the FormTypes or Controller however I don't see how we would do the equivalent of:

`->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create Post'))`

in the (what I assume is TWIG) templates. Can someone give an example of how this should be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, in your twig template:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}

<input type="submit" value="Save" />

{{ form_end(form) }}
```